# Changing max inode count number in ext3 filesystem in Cent OS

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3, inode

Assuming that I use ext3 filesystem in Cent OS:
Can I increase the number of Free Inodes in the filesystem? If Yes how?
When I run 
`tune2fs -l /dev/sda1`
it got these inodes statistics:

```
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery sparse_super
Inode count:              26104
Free inodes:              26069
Inodes per group:         2008
Inode blocks per group:   251
First inode:              11
Inode size:               128
Journal inode:            8
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Comment: Did you search ?!

http://superuser.com/questions/158031/how-to-change-the-inode-size-on-an-ext3-partition

Comment: I don't want to change the inode size(wich is by default 128 bytes) but the max inode count.

Comment: @terdon ext filesystems are limited in size and number of files. This is about the latter. Even if you have terabytes of free disk space, if you're out of inodes, no new files can be created.

Comment: @DanielBeck, ah, of course, sorry not thinking straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to increase the number of Inode in ext3 filesystem we need to remake the filesystem using `mke2fs` with the `-i` option we can set the byte-per-inode ratio which will affect the number of inodes. Otherwise the `-N` option allows to specify the exact number of inodes.